# Retrieve lowest priority MX record from PHP

Tags: php, dns

I need to get MX records from a domain but only the one with the highest priority (lowest number).

I've played around a fair amount but haven't been able to work out how to only return the one result.

```
   $results = dns_get_record($domain, DNS_MX);

   foreach ($results as $result)
   {
    $A = dns_get_record($result['target'], DNS_A);
    foreach ($A as $ip)
    { 
             echo $ip['ip'];
    }
   }
```

That gives me what I want to end up with but for every MX record that the domain has.

If somebody could point me in the right direction that would be great!

Cheers!

Comment: There should be a `$result['pri']` available to you to sort by. Or use the `getmxrr` function.

Comment: There is indeed I just don't know how to use it to get what I need.

Comment: @ceejayoz nice call on `getmxrr()`, I'd never heard of that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `array_column()` function to collect all the priorities, and then use array_filter to pull out the smallest:

```
// get all the results
$results = dns_get_record($domain, DNS_MX);
// find the lowest value in the "pri" column
$target_pri = min(array_column($results, "pri"));
$highest_pri = array_filter(
    $results,
    // keep anything that matches the lowest (could be more than one)
    function($item) use($target_pri) {return $item["pri"] === $target_pri;}
);
// now loop through each of them, finding all their IP addresses
foreach ($highest_pri as $mx) {
    echo "$mx[target]: ";
    $results = dns_get_record($mx["target"], DNS_A);
    foreach ($results as $a) {
        echo "$a[ip] ";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you!!